# Picking college degree (want to be games programmer)

Tags: software-engineering, education, career

Alright, so I know there's plenty of questions that have to do with college degrees on this site, but I don't feel that any of them really answer my question. I recently got accepted into Northeastern University. The thing that drew me to the university was not only that it appears to have a comprehensive computer science program, but that it offers combined majors with the other colleges. Since i'm interested in both game art and game programming, I applied to the Computer Science and Digital Art major. However, after looking at the other combined majors, I wondering if I picked the one that is right for me.

The five majors I'm currently looking at right now:

**Computer Science and Digital Art:**

- Pros: Teaches both programming and art fundamentals.
- Cons: The mathematics requirements are the weakest of the five majors
  (only require linear algebra).

**Computer Science and Game Design:**

- Pros: Very comprehensive in both computer science and game design.
  Requires the most computer science courses out of the 5 majors (the
  extra courses are game design specific). I'd be the most likely to
  meet like minded peers in this major as well.
- Cons: Doesn't really touch on subjects of game art at all. You are
  allowed to take two art+design electives, that's it.

**Computer Engineering and Computer Science:**

- Pros: Gives a comprehensive education on computing in general
  (hardware and software). The biggest benefit of this major, I feel,
  is that it would teach me how to think. By that, I mean it would
  teach me to think in such a way that it'd be very easy to dive into
  other aspects of both computer engineering and computer science (more
  so than the other majors).
- Cons: It's a computer engineering major first, and a computer science
  major second. Some of the information I learn may be pretty much
  useless.

**Computer Science and mathematics:**

- Pros: Naturally, it has the most math courses of any other major.
- Cons: The only major con is that I'm not really crazy about math, and
  don't know if I really want to subject myself to a bunch of it.

**Computer Science and physics**

- Pros: It's actually pretty well split among math, physics, and
  computer science.
- Cons: Like the computer engineering major, some of the information I
  learn may be pretty much useless.

I don't want this post to be ridiculously long so forgive me if I'm not specific enough. I'm guess I'm torn between different beliefs. Computer Science and Digital Art/Game Design would probably be the most fun majors for me, since they'd suit my personal interests. However, the other majors would give me information that would be useful in a broader sense (I could apply them outside the fields of game design / interactive media). I don't think any one of these majors will prepare me **completely** for the games industry, not even the game design one. However, I do think that no matter which of these majors I pick, I'll still be able to get into the game industry.